# How do I fix an issue with users passwords not working after importing users from one firebase project to another?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I recently set up a new firebase project to import existing users from one project to another but after a successful import, none of the passwords work when trying to authenticate the users in the new project

The import/export operations were done using the firebase cli tools v6.4.0

I expected that after the import, users will be able to still sign in with their already existing passwords but the actual result was a firebase error sayings the password is either incorrect or the user does not exist

Comment: Having the same problem, why let you import and export, if the passwords don't work after!!

Comment: Actually I fixed the issue. When importing users from an old to a new project, you need to use the password hash parameters of the old project in your import command. When the user opens up the app next, all they need to do is sign in again and the password will be rehashed and everything works fine.

Comment: Yes thanks, I got it working also!